# Inner workings of yaml-cpp vs c++ maps

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

Just a quick question about the inner workings of yaml-cpp.

I noticed that when i tried to look up a key that didn't exist i got an error such as:

```
yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad conversion
```

I was suprised by this because I would have assumed by this point post loading we would be operating directly off an in memory map

If i do lookup such as

```
string foo = myyaml["bar"]["foo"].as<string>();
```

Does that happen as efficiently as if I had a strongly typed map. Would it be more efficient if I preprocess the things i know to exist in the yaml into a c++ map and access them directly rather than via the node?

I guess i'm asking if the perf of a map is faster than acessing a node

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup in a map in yaml-cpp is `O(n)` - it loops through all entries in the map. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=178) on the project page.

Lookup in `std::map` is `O(log n)` - it stores keys in order, and binary searches to find your key. So if you have a large number of keys, it might be faster to preprocess your data. But you should probably measure first :)

Comment: Thanks I implemented both direct lookups to yaml-cpp and to c++ maps carrying the same data with no other code changes. (I simple preprocess the bits i need to look up a lot into 3 other maps). It worked out about 43% less cpu on average. It's a very nice and easy to use library by the way. :)